# razor syntax question - where is the missing } in this? (I am using knockoutjs but I think that's unrelated, ignore that part)

Tags: web-applications, razor, knockout.js

It's my first time using the razor viewengine, could some one assist me? I get the following error:
 Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Source Error:

```
Line 12: <tr>
Line 13: 
Line 14: @foreach(string fieldName in Model.FieldNames) {
Line 15:         if(Model.FieldTypes[fieldName]=="label") {
Line 16:       @:  <td class="label" data-bind="text: @fieldName"></td>
```

My code is:

```
@foreach(string fieldName in Model.FieldNames) {
        if(Model.FieldTypes[fieldName]=="label") {
      @:  <td class="label" data-bind="text: @fieldName"></td>
        }
        else if(Model.FieldTypes[fieldName]=="text") {
      @:   <td class="text"><input type="text" data-bind="value: @fieldName, event: {focus: highlightField, blur: updateUser}"/></td>
        }
        else if(Model.FieldTypes[fieldName]=="number") {
     @:   <td class="number"><input type="text" data-bind="value: @fieldName, event: {focus: highlightField, blur: updateUser}"/></td>
        }
      else if(Model.FieldTypes[fieldName].Contains("dropdown") {
     @:   <td class="text"><select id='groupSelect' data-bind="options: @Model.FieldTypes[fieldName].Replace("dropdown", ""), optionsText: 'Name', selectedOptions: selectedUserGroupValue, event: {focus: highlightField, blur: updateUser}"></select>
        } 
     }
```

What's funny is it works perfectly if I comment out this last part:

```
@*
 else if(Model.FieldTypes[fieldName].Contains("dropdown") {
     @:   <td class="text"><select id='groupSelect' data-bind="options: @Model.FieldTypes[fieldName].Replace("dropdown", ""), optionsText: 'Name', selectedOptions: selectedUserGroupValue, event: {focus: highlightField, blur: updateUser}"></select>
        } 
*@
```

Anyone have any clue why adding this section causes this error?

Much appreciated.

Comment: If you could put the code in code syntax it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Note that you don't need the `@:` inside the `if` bodies

Comment: What do you mean by code in code syntax?

Comment: When I took out the @: in the lines under each if and elseif it gave an error again... Any ideas what a good reference on razor syntax is? I googled it and got a page that covers just really basic examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last if condition is missing a ")".

Comment: Thanks, wow I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
@foreach (string fieldName in Model.FieldNames)
{
    if (Model.FieldTypes[fieldName] == "label")
    {
    }
    else if (Model.FieldTypes[fieldName] == "text")
    {
    }
    else if (Model.FieldTypes[fieldName] == "number")
    {
    }
    else if (Model.FieldTypes[fieldName].Contains("dropdown"))
    {
    }
}
```